# Satisfying unusual norm equation over the vector space of all real sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been tackling this question about norms and I have done all the standard parts to the question I am just really struggling with the extension part of the question. I will state the whole question as I am unsure if any of the prior information is needed for the last part.

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ of all real sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ and let V be the set of all sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ such $x_j\neq 0$ for only finely many j. 
The parts of the question which I have done are as follows:

i) Show that V is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and so a vector space in its own right.

ii) Check that $\left \|x  \right \|_\infty:=max_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_j|$ is a norm on V

iii) Define $T:V\to V$ by setting the j-th term of $T(x)$ to be $jx_j$. Show that T is linear but not continuous.

Then this is the extension part which I cannot wrap my head around:

iv) By considering norms of the form $\left \|x  \right \|=max_jk_j|x_j|$, or otherwise, find two norms $\left \|\cdot\right \|_a$ and $\left \|\cdot\right \|_b$ such that:
$$\underset{\left \|x\right \|_a=1}{sup}\left \|x\right \|_b=\underset{\left \|x\right \|_b=1}{sup}\left \|x\right \|_a=\infty$$

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Hint: for one norm, choose $k_i$ to be 'small' for even $i$ and 'large' for odd $i,$ and vice versa for the other norm.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: let $\Vert x \Vert_a = | x_1 |$ and similarly $\Vert x \Vert_b = | x_2 |$. Consider the sequence $(x^n)_n$ defined by $x^n = (1,n,0,0,\ldots)$, noting that $\Vert x^n \Vert_a = 1$. What can you say about $\Vert x^n \Vert_b$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?